# Trouble with grounding 3d object

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I am trying to make a simple movement shooter and I am running into a simple issue that is stopping my progress, that is my collider not registering it is one the ground

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10;
    public float forward;
    public float right;
    private int jumpcount;
    public bool isOnGround;
    bool isAlive;
    Rigidbody player;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        isAlive = true;
        player = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement();
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isOnGround){
            player.AddForce(Vector3.up, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
    void movement()
    {
        forward = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        right = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void OnCollisionstay(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.transform.tag == "Ground")
        {
            isOnGround = true;
        } else
        {
            isOnGround = false;
        }
    }
}
```

my code reads as follows and I have given the ground a mesh collider and the object a cylander collider yet is on ground remains false.

I have tried variations of the on collision command yet none have worked

Comment: You may want to look into setting your IDE up properly. As @Simeon Borisov mentioned, these methods are case sensitive. If you set up your IDE properly (go into settings -> prefs -> external tools -> choose your IDE -> regenerate project files -> relaunch your IDE) you would get autocompletions allowing for this to happen less.

Answer (score 0):

In C# the method names are case sensitive

try changing `OnCollisionstay` to `OnCollisionStay`

and maybe add a `Debug.Log()` in that method to see if it gets trigggered.

You can also pasting in the example method provided in the [unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionStay.html)